# configuring configuration directory for faster access

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ssd

I recently upgraded my laptop with an SSD, and my programs seem to load faster, but, some of them still require a decent load time.

The SSD is mounted at: `/` where as my HDD is mounted as `/home/<username>` , now I think the program load time is being throttled because the configuration files for my programs still search the HDD for initial setup. (Most of these configurations are stored in the `.config` folder in `/home/<username>`)

So, I need a way to tell ubuntu this:

> From now on, save my configuration files on my SSD's location
> `/user/config` and don't search my HDD for it.

I'd only like to use my HDD for long term storage use. How do  I tell ubuntu this.

Comment: Have you considered keeping your home dir on the SSD as well, and only keep specific folders (e.g. `~/Videos`, `~/Pictures`, `~/Documents`) on the HDD? That would automatically keep configuration and caches on your SSD.

Comment: um, that is true, but, the downloads usually tends to be large, and SSDs are usually relatively small so it would require a lot of move operations daily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration files are fairly small -- I doubt that having these small files on your hard disk is the source of your speed problems.

However, one easy solution to your problem is to just create the directory in your SSD and then place a symbolic link from `~/.config/` to it.  ie.,

```
 sudo mkdir /user/config/
 sudo chown -R <user> /user/config/
 <Either remove ~/.config/ or move it to /user/config/>
 ln -s -f /user/config ~/.config
```

I guess that will do what you want?

Comment: I think that /user/config would require read write permission for io operations? Is sudo chown -R <user> /user/config used for preventing permission denial on every io? could you explain that, please? Also, whenever a program searches for .config file, it would be redirected to the SSD? I think this would be a better solution then what I had been thinking. Please explain these to me.

Comment: +1: Smart idea, simply executed, and maintainable.

Comment: @bzal So, assuming your username is `bzal`, that second line suggests you change the ownership of `/user/config/` to `bzal`.  (And you might as well do `/user/`, also.)  A symbolic link is basically the same as a Windows shortcut, if that helps.  It's a pointer that takes you from `~/.config/` to `/user/config/`.  The only "harm" is if you have to reinstall Ubuntu and wipe the `/` directory, you need to remember about this particular directory.  Many people like keeping `/home` separate for these types of emergencies.  I suggest you try with a directory like `test` and you'll see what I mean.